# ApplicationUserManager doesn't use my custom UserStore implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I created a new MVC5 Application with ASP.NET Identity. I haven't changed lot of the files. This is the error I get:

[image: Exception when using ApplicationManager]

The following changes in the project differ from the VisualStudio template:

#### ApplicationUserManager.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<User> userStore)
        : base(userStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        // Use DI to resolve the UserStore
        var userStore = (IUserStore<User>) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IUserStore<User>));

        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);

        // rest is same as in the template ...
    }
}
```

My DependencyResolver is Ninject. I created the following Bindings for it:

```
Bind<IMyDbContextFactory>().To<MyDbContextFactory>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserStore>().WithConstructorArgument("factory", factory => Kernel.Get<MyDbContextFactory>());
```

#### UserStore.cs

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>,
    IUserLockoutStore<User, string>,
    IUserPasswordStore<User>,
    IUserTwoFactorStore<User, string>,
    IUserEmailStore<User>
{
    private readonly IMyDbContextFactory _factory;

    public UserStore(IMyDbContextFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing to dispose here
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        using (var context = _factory.CreateContext())
        {
            // TODO: Validation
            context.Users.Add(user);
            var result = context.SaveChanges();
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }

    // the rest of the implementend methods from the interfaces ...
}
```

And for the sake of completeness the User entity, the DbContext and the factory I use to retrieve the DbContext in `UserStore.cs`

#### User.cs

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public object PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> ApplicationUserLogins { get; set; }
}
```

#### MyDbContextFactory.cs

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IMyDbContextFactory
{
    public IMyDbContext CreateContext()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

#### MyDbContext.cs

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDbContextConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    // DbSets, OnModelCreating and other stuff ...
}
```

The Exception implies that UserManager is null. But that's not true:

[image]

It seems that `ApplicationUserManager` doesn't really use (or sets) my injected UserStore. But why is that?

Comment: How do you get `UserManager` into the controller? by default it is extracted from `OwinContext`, not from your DI. And it seems like `UserManager` is null in your exception message.

Comment: UserManager is still extracted from `OwinContext`. I didn't change that part of the application. I still use `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` in `Startup.Auth.cs`. No, UserManager is not null. (I added a screenshot to my question)

Comment: So if you step through ` ApplicationUserManager.Create` method. Do you get `UserStore` returned to you from `DependencyResolver`? Are any other objects resolved by `DependencyResolver`?

Comment: The DependencyResolver works as it should. I also tried using the concrete classes directly without success. This is not the issue. In the meantime I found out, what the problem was. I'm posting an answer right now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found it out, but it was a tough one.

The first method of the `UserStore` that gets called from the `ApplicationUserManager` is `SetPasswordHashAsync`. (Don't ask me why -.-)

My implementation of that method returned `null`. That was wrong for two reasons

1. I should not write `return null;` but `return Task.FromResult<Task>(null);`, since it's an async method. (Or throw an Exception). Because of that, I received that useless YSOD.
2. The UserManager calls `SetPasswordHashAsync` first. Again, don't ask me why. Since I used the `/Account/Register` Action to register a new user, I simply didn't expect that the UserManager first tries to set the password. I mean, there is no user yet. That's why I want to register one. WTF?

To summarize: The UserManager did actually use my UserStore, but not as I expected it.

Comment: `SetPasswordHashAsync` actually updates values on class instance, not in database. Check the source code for the framework implementation - you'll see why it is done that way.